# postfix redirect e-mails from same domain to another mailserver

Tags: email, debian, postfix-mta

So my question is, for a company we have an old exchange server (they don't want to upgrade or transfer) that is nearly dying from e-mails. But these are just coming from one Mailbox.

So my plan was, redirect info@example.de to another mailbox like info@outlook.onmicrosoft.com.

The other E-Mails should be routed as expected...

```
# virtual postfix file
info@example.de info@outlook.onmicrosoft.com
@example.de @example.de
```

For this I also have a transport File.

```
example.de smtp:mx.mail.de
```

My problem now is, the redirect is getting bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)

```
2B2DEE7: to=<timo.bergen@example.de>, relay=none, delay=0.08, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this, just had to append the Domain to "mydestinations".

```
mydestination = $myhostname, web-p03.hosting.it.local, localhost.hosting.it.local, , localhost , example.de
```